# Random Order by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I got the data using this query:

[image]

```
SELECT PT.ID AS ProductTypeId,
       PT.ProductType,
       PTPS.ID AS AssetId,
       PTPS.Ordinal AS AssetOrdinal,
       CASE
           WHEN PTPS.LinkType = 2
               THEN
               --DS.ServerRootURL + 'Videos/ProductTypes/' +
               --PTPSMaterialImage.LinkURL
               (
                   SELECT TOP 1 LinkURL
                   FROM ProductTypesPblmSolutions
                   WHERE ProductTypeId = PT.ID
                       AND LinkType = 1
                   ORDER BY ID DESC
               )
           ELSE PTPS.LinkURL
       END AS MaterialImage,
       ATL.LinkType
FROM ProductTypes PT
INNER JOIN ProductTypesToApps PTA ON PT.ID = PTA.ProductTypeId
INNER JOIN ProductTypesPblmSolutions PTPS ON PTPS.ProductTypeId = PT.ID
INNER JOIN DealerSettings DS ON DS.DealerId = 23
INNER JOIN AttachmentLinkTypes ATL ON ATL.ID = PTPS.LinkType
WHERE PTA.AppId = 3
    AND (PT.ID = 202 OR 202 IS NULL)
    AND (ISNULL(PTPS.IsDeleted, 0) = 0)
ORDER BY PTPS.Ordinal
```

Let's talk about the `materialimage` column. I have to get two different images for this producttype but for now I am getting the same product.

There are lot of linkurls exist for this product. Please refer this query below and its data.

```
SELECT ProductTypeId,
       linkurl,
       linktype
FROM ProductTypesPblmSolutions
WHERE ProductTypeId = 202
    AND linktype = 1
```

[image]

The same thing I used it as subquery in my Main query

How do I get different images in this column.

I tried with `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY NEWID()` but it does NOT work.

Comment: Please avoid using irrelevant tags. find out what version of sql server you are working with and remove all the other version tags.

Comment: `ORDER BY NEWID()` is the usual go-to method of getting 'random' ordering; so show a small, testable example, of you using it and how "it does not work" Then you're more likely to get fast help

Comment: I tried with either rand() or newid() in order by clause but I didn't get different images in my main query

Comment: Seeing as you show a CASE for `LinkType = 2`, but show data for `LinkType = 1`, then it seems there's either something illogical about the data or you're not showing us the appropriate data. I would think as Gordon mentions, you do not hit your case statement. Try changing `THEN` to select just `'2'` and your `ELSE` to select `'1'`. Also try to make a sql fiddle we can test on.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, the subquery should look like:

```
            (SELECT TOP 1 ptps2.LinkURL
             FROM ProductTypesPblmSolutions ptps2
             WHERE ptps2.ProductTypeId = PT.Id AND
                   ptps2.LinkType = 1
             ORDER BY NEWID()
            )
```

Note the use of qualified column names and the `NEWID()` in the `ORDER BY`.

I recommend always using qualified column names.  This is *especially* true in correlated subqueries, where errors are easy to make and very difficult to find (although that might not be the problem in this particular case).

If you see no effect from this, then I would assume that the `else` component of the `case` is being executed, rather than the subquery.

Comment: I tried it but I am getting the same values for that two rows

Comment: Then the subquery is probably not being executed, and you are getting the `else` value.

Comment: I am hitting my heads for the past couple of hours to get the expected result in that subquery part but nothing works for me. Please see my second sample data for your reference

Comment: Just now I confirmed that it went through the Case when part not in the else part

Comment: Newid() value is same for the two records that I highlighted. I don't know how do I bring two different newid()'s for these two records.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP(1) t.LinkURL
FROM dbo.ProductTypesPblmSolutions t
WHERE t.ProductTypeId = PT.ID
    AND t.LinkType = 1
ORDER BY NEWID(), PT.ID -- additional calculation
```

Example #1:

```
SELECT TOP(10) s.number, (
    SELECT TOP(1) s1.number
    FROM [master].dbo.spt_values s1
    WHERE s1.[type] = s.[type]
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)
FROM [master].dbo.spt_values s
WHERE s.[type] = 'P'
```

Output:

```
----------- -----------
0           844
1           844
2           844
3           844
4           844
5           844
6           844
7           844
8           844
9           844
```

Example #2:

```
SELECT TOP(10) s.number, (
    SELECT TOP(1) s1.number
    FROM [master].dbo.spt_values s1
    WHERE s1.[type] = s.[type]
    ORDER BY NEWID(), s.[type] -- <<<< additional calculation
)
FROM [master].dbo.spt_values s
WHERE s.[type] = 'P'
```

Output:

```
----------- -----------
0           428
1           801
2           550
3           1619
4           178
5           17
6           1702
7           683
8           352
9           1844
```

Comment: I already tried like this but I am getting the same values in that column

Comment: @NewUser check my examples :)